# Trying to only update the specific array in Firestore but what it does is add more data in the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this data structure in Firestore:

[image]

Expected output: I will only update the `array[1]` which is `M`.

What it currently does: Instead of only updating the `array[1]`  it added another data in the  `array`. So instead of having only indexes `0,1,2` it became `0,1,2,3`

```
 const [category, setCategory] = useState([]);
//useEffect to get all of the categories


const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);
const [edit, setEdit] = useState();



const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

const ref = doc(db, "category", state);
await updateDoc(ref, {
  category: edit,
  options: arrayUnion(options),
});

console.log("updated")
 };
```

**Forms:**

```
{category &&
          category.map((category, index) => (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                  <TextField
                    defaultValue={category.cat}
                    type="text"
                    value={categoryEdit}
                    fullWidth
                    onChange={(e) => setCategoryEdit(e.target.value)}
                  />
                      {category.options.map((i) => (
                        <TextField
                          type="text"
                          defaultValue={i}
                          variant="outlined"
                          fullWidth
                          value={options[i]}
                          onChange={(e) => setOptions(e.target.value)}
                        />
                      ))}
         
                  </>
                )}
                <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
            </form>
          ))}
```

Comment: I also think that this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-in-firestore-cdb611a56073) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to update an item in an array field with either `arrayUnion` or otherwise. You'll have to:

1. Read the document into your application
2. Get the full array
3. Update the one item in the array
4. Write the full array back to the document

Also see:

- [Firestore Update single item in an array field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187985/firestore-update-single-item-in-an-array-field)
- [Cloud firestore: Update field values in nested array object with dot notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64428892/cloud-firestore-update-field-values-in-nested-array-object-with-dot-notation/64429573#64429573)
- [How can I update an object inside of an array in firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62417069/how-can-i-update-an-object-inside-of-an-array-in-firestore/62418875#62418875)