# How to append a nested array value in Firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore documented modeled like this:

[image]

In each document, there can be multiple messages, and in each message, there can be multiple comments. Im trying to update the comments with the following:

```
Future<void> updateStingrayComment(
   Comment? comment, String? stingrayid) async {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('stingrays')
        .doc(stingrayid)
        .update({
          'messages': {
            'comments': FieldValue.arrayUnion([Comment.toJson(comment)])
          }
        })
```

I recognize Im not using a messageID to attach the comment to, but I'm not sure how I would do that. Anyone have any ideas? Im using this in flutter, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Have you considered putting your messages and comments into sub-collections?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `messages` is an array field, and there is no operation to **update** an item in an array field.

You will have to:

1. Read the array from the document into your application code
2. Update the array in memory
3. Write the entire array back to the document

Comment: I see, so would I have to update the entire document every time someone comments? IE:

.update('message':NewMappedMessage)

Comment: At said in step #3: you'll have to write the entire array back to the document.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with a similar situation, I ended up with a kindof brute force solution. Instead of a nested list of comments, I made a separate list called 'comments'. Every message will have a message ID, which gets passed to respective comments, and all comments will be queried based on their message ID.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, as of October 2023, you should be able to use a combination of dot notation (see https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects) and arrayUnion (see https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects) to achieve the desired effect.

However, please note, you cannot update members of the array, only add to them. See: [Cloud firestore: Update field values in nested array object with dot notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64428892/cloud-firestore-update-field-values-in-nested-array-object-with-dot-notation)